# Updating data stored in DynamoDB using AWS Amplify graphqlOperation

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql

I am trying to update the user data using the API from AWS Amplify. I can add new record to the connected table with the createUser function imported from graphql mutation but the updateUser doesn't work and returning error. The function I used is defined as below:

```
async function UpdateUsers() {
    try {
      const user = {
        role: 'student',
        fname: formState.fname,
        lname: formState.lname,
        age: formState.age,
        school: formState.school,
        class_name: formState.class_name,
        sid: formState.sid,
        test1: formState.test1,
        test2: formState.test2,
        test3: formState.test3
      }
      const newData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(updateUser, {input: user}))
    } catch (err) {
      alert('Error when updating user', err)
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried to do it another way by deleting the old record and create a new one. But the deleteUser function generated automatically from graphql mutation did not work either.